# Design pattern for preallocating data and passing it around in Julia

Tags: julia

I am looking to improve certain aspects of how I write Julia code for a computation heavy program that operates on large arrays and matrices.

There are a lot of private functions that do intermediate processing and the system was previously designed in C++ in such a way that memory was handled explicitly by a custom object to avoid constant reinitialization and reallocation. This is inline with [Julia's tips on performance](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#Pre-allocating-outputs-1).

The way I've found this translates to Julia is:

```
mutable struct Bar
   # A data structure holding data for a domain object
end

mutable struct FooData
    # A data structure holding intermediate computation variables
    data::Array{Float32, 1}

    function FooData()
       new(Array{Float32, 1}(undef, 10000)
    end
end


function foo!(data::FooData, b::Bar, param1, param2)
    # modify data and return something
end

data = FooData()
for i=1:100
    foo!(data, ...)
end
```

Often times foo! does more than one thing. This is mainly to combine operations for performance reasons. This makes naming foo and FooData particularly difficult.

My questions are:

1. Is there a nicer way of dealing with preallocating data? The code in C++ for example had a separate Singleton object that managed the preallocated data and passed pointers around. The memory was created with malloc and pointers were void* that were then type cast to whatever is needed. They are released by the manager object when not needed anymore.
2. How do you deal with intermediate functions? There is no encapsulation in Julia to hide them. Do you name them differently?

Comment: Not an answer, just pointing out that arrays in Julia are mutable, even when inside an immutable struct. For example, you could define `struct FooData ; data::Vector{Float64} ; end` (an immutable) and still do `foodata.data[3:4] = rand(2)`. You only need to make `FooData` mutable if you want to do operations like `foodata.data = rand(5)`, ie re-allocating the entire field `data`. I only mention this because based on your question, it sounds like you might only want to modify the elements of `data` rather than `FooData` itself...

Comment: Sometimes, I make FooData mutable to allow the certain parts of its memory to be freed. For example, by saying foodata.data = nothing. My understanding is that triggers the garbage collector. If data is of type ::Union{Nothing, Array{Float32,1}}, I'm hoping that the memory of the array is indeed freed.

Comment: That makes sense, although I'm not sure if garbage collection would be automatic. You might need to force it with `gc()`. If you don't get an answer within a day or two, I'd consider asking the question on the [Discourse page](https://discourse.julialang.org/).

Comment: I don't think that will trigger the garbage collector. Normally you let Julia handle memory via scope, instead of explicitly trying to free it.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know what you mean by a nicer way - how is it not nice? In your MWE there is no need at all for the `FooData` type, as you can just pass around a Vector, but maybe the actual use case is more complex. You don't need to have quite as much defined in objects as you do in C++.

To answer your second question, local functions are often named like `_foobar`. But encapsulation is taken care of by Modules - you simply don't export those functions from your Module. They are not `private` in you can still use them if you like (with `MyModule._foobar()`), but then it's your own responsibility. Such convention-over-enforcement is common in Julia.

Comment: I've found the loss of explicit function ownership has created a class of objects which I don't know where to place. In OO, objects own methods. This in my mind gives objects a shared responsibility over the domain data and the functions. In the case where the results of intermediate operations need to be cached for performance, the struct doing the caching can be stored in this OO object. However, in Julia, since the function and object are separate, I am not so sure where that struct now belongs as that struct is more tied to the function than to the domain data.

Comment: I tend to cache intermediate results in the object. You can either have a separate type that includes the cache, or a field in the object of type cache::Ref{Union{T, Nothing}} where T is the type of your intermediate. But that's a general solution to something that might have another specific answer for your use case - what is the use exactly?